# Passing multiple table id's to a view Laravel

Tags: laravel-5, model-view-controller

So here is my problem. I am trying to create two entries for two tables Customer and Booking. Where customer id is a foreign key in bookings table and the primary key in the customer table.
What I want to do is to pass the newly generated customer id and the booking id to another function in the same controller(edit function).So that I can update the Booking table column with the generated customer id. Is there an easy way to do this stuff.

```
        $booking =new Booking;
        $customer=new Customer;
        $booking->piklocation=$request->input('piklocation');
        $booking->date=$request->input('date');
        $customer=new Customer;
        $booking->save();
        $customer->save();
        return redirect()->route('booking.edit', $booking->id,$customer->id);
    }


}
/**
 * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function edit($id,$id2)
{
    //Validation of the edit code
    $booking = Booking::find($id);
    $customer=Customer::find($id2);
    return view('pages.vehicleselect')->with('booking',$booking)->with('customer',$customer);

}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do. That is the problem here?

Comment: I am trying to send data to two tables Booking and Customers table. I don't know how to get  the right customer id from customer table and send it to the column in booking tables. This is a senario where a user comes and fill a form including customer details(hs first name,last name..) and booking details(Booking date..). I want to send the data to 2 tables

Answer (score 0):

you should use eloquent relationship
you can use this doc base on your tables relationship
[[mant to many relation DOC]](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many)

and use this relations to get bookings of a customer:

```
Customer::with('booking')->find($customer_id);
```

*booking is relation name in customer Model

Comment: hey, Thanks a lot. I have added the relationships in my model. But the problem is all the data that should go to 2 tables(booking and customer) are in a single form. As I said the customerid is a foreign key in the booking table. How can I send the data using elequent to 2 tables
eg-Customer name  should go to the customer table and his relevant booking details should go to booking table?